# Selenium - click on anchor tag which is within a ul tag with attribute style="display: none;

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, display

```html
<div id="menu1Div" style="float: right;">
 <ul id="menu1" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-menu-icons" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-2">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
   <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>  Actions
   </a>
   <ul class="menuUL ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display: none; top: 4px; left: 101.8px;" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
    <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_14" role="presentation">
     <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(14)" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-desktop"></span>Account Details
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_1" role="presentation">
     <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(1)" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-search"></span>Change Password
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_2" role="presentation">
     <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(2)" id="ui-id-7" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-files-o"></span>My Works
     </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_3" role="presentation">
     <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(3)" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-user"></span>My Page
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_4" role="presentation">
     <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(4)" id="ui-id-10" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-briefcase"></span>My Resources
     </a>
    </li>
    
    
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

There is a login page where the below mentioned html gets loaded after complete login. So in order to get the clickable element, i tried to make Thread sleep as follows :

```
Thread.sleep(3000L);
```

Even after this, it says element is not found. now i want to write an automated selenium code to click on "Change Password" which is in nested li.
I have tried different selectors but resulted with negative results.

Selenium code:

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.menuUL>li.menuLI.ui-menu-item>a"));
elems.get(0).click();//for the 1st element
elems.get(1).click();//for the 2nd element
elems.get(2).click();
```

HTML :

```
<div id="menu1Div" style="float: right;">
    <ul id="menu1" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-menu-icons" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-2">
        <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
            <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>  Actions
            </a>
            <ul class="menuUL ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display: none; top: 4px; left: 101.8px;" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
                <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_14" role="presentation">
                    <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(14)" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                        <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-desktop"></span>Account Details
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_1" role="presentation">
                    <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(1)" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                        <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-search"></span>Change Password
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_2" role="presentation">
                    <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(2)" id="ui-id-7" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                        <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-files-o"></span>My Works
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_3" role="presentation">
                    <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(3)" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                        <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-user"></span>My Page
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuLI ui-menu-item" id="MenuKey_4" role="presentation">
                    <a class="menuAnchor ui-corner-all" href="#" style="padding-left: 0.7em;" onclick="actionSelected(4)" id="ui-id-10" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                        <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-briefcase"></span>My Resources
                    </a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.menuUL>li.menuLI.ui-menu-item>a"));
```

should fix your problem.

Also in your HTML code there is `style="display: none;` because of which Account Details Change Password My Works My Page My Resources are not visible. When the element is not visible even if you try `Thread.sleep(3000L);` you will not be able to click on the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code if you look at the following line

```
<ul class="menuUL ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display: none; top: 4px; left: 101.8px;" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
```

you will see the **display: none;** attribute. This will hide the element and all its sub elements from view. So selenium can find the element but is not able to perform an action.

### Solution 1

You have to ask the dev guy to display the element. (Remove the display: none; for the element). But the problem is why is it hidden in the first place?

### Solution 2

Fire a javascript command instead of the selenium command for the element. The JavaScript command will work even if the element is not visible on the page.

```
List elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.menuUL>li.menuLI.ui-menu-item>a"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elems.get(0)); // select the element index from elemennt list as you need
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to perform your operation:-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='menuUL ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all']"));

js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: fixed;')",element);

List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.menuUL>li.menuLI.ui-menu-item>a"));

  elems.get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Prathibha and @debugger89 have pointed to the right direction that the `<ul>` tag containing the `<li>` tags have the attribute **style="display: none;**. So to click on the element with text as **Change Password** you can use the following code block :

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;  
// lines of code
WebElement ulContainer = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.menuUL.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all[role='menu']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", ulContainer);
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.menuUL li.menuLI.ui-menu-item[role='presentation'] > a"));
for(WebElement ele:elems)
    if(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Change Password"))
    {
        ele.click();
        break;
    }
```